# Trying to save the status of radio groups according to a select radio button

Tags: java, android

I am working on a project where I have many radio buttons in several radio groups. What I would like to do is save the configuration of all the radio groups in accordance to a specific button in the first radio group. For example the first radio group is called select and I have 4 different select radio buttons. When I switch from the 4 buttons inside that group I would like the other radio group buttons to be filled in automatically to that of what they were previously, I would also like to save the configuration of the current button when it is switched through out the radio group. So for example if a radio button in the first radio group is switched it remembers the configuration of the previous one and will automatically load itself again when it comes back to that view.

Answer (score 1):

Create a model that models all of this.  Use a property change listener (or many other listeners) to allow you to listen for update in state.  The state will be updated whenever you call a setter on the model.

For example, when you set the outer radio button group to the 2nd button, then the model can throw property change events for all of the buttons which depend on that state.  The getters for the state of the inner radio buttons can depend on the state of the outer button.

You will probably need to add listeners in the view that listen for user actions on the buttons.  The actions in these listeners will call the setters on the model.  Be careful to not cause recursive events this way.

Example:

This is an example of the model you could build.  Say you have an outer radio button group with 2 buttons and single inner button group with 3 buttons.  The inner group options are always the same regardless of the selected outer button.

```
public class Model {
    private int outerSelected = 0; // 0 or 1
    private InnerModel[] innerModels = new InnerModel[2];

    private class InnerModel {
        private int selected = 0; // 0, 1, or 2

        public void setSelected(int selected) {
            this.selected = selected;
            // Send event
        }

        public int getSelected() {
            return selected;
        }
    }

    public int getSelectedInnerModel() {
        return innerModels[outerSelected];
    }

    public int setOuterSelected(int outerSelected) {
        this.outerSelected = outerSelected;
        // send event for selectedInnerModel change
        // If you use beans binding, this should cause the view to re-query the 
        // getSelected on the InnerModel as well
    }
}
```

I wouldn't suggest you actually use integers.  The enum is a better idea, but I didn't write it out.  Optionally, you can make this Model class be private inside your view.

Comment: Thank for the reply. What I have done so far is I have an OnCheckedChangeListener that listens to what button in the main radio group is selected. When activated it sets an enum function to either first second third fourth. What I do then is listen to changes in the other radio groups. When a radio button is clicked in the other radio groups i save the state to a temp boolean, followed by a switch statement that switches views based off the enum. In the    case I call a save function for the radio group based off the enum.

Comment: I then have a load function which sets the states of the buttons to what the temp had stored. This method seems to work but is buggy and not all the settings get saved and loaded accurately.

Comment: The key, IMO, is to have a separate class that models the state of all of the buttons.  I will edit for a small example.